# Automatically name class methods in IDA

Tags: ida, disassembly, static-analysis

Let's say I have:

```
mov ecx, [g_pMyClassObj] ; type CMyClass
call sub_B00BA ; a thiscall function
```

Is there a feature/plugin/script to automatically rename all subroutine occurrences to:

```
mov ecx, [g_pMyClassObj] ; type CMyClass
call CMyClass__B00BA
```

Comment: Which Ida version are you using? Do you have HexRays decompiler?

Comment: I am using IDA version 7.7, And yes I have HexRays Decompiler and use it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as IDA is concerned it's programmable in almost every manner thanks to the scripting engine. When it comes to renaming a subroutine in IDA it can be achieved either using idc scripts or by using idapython.

Although renaming class methods in IDA automatically can be a tough task because you have to provide much more information to IDA such as object-name, calling conventions etc. However, a more general occurrence of a subroutine can easily be renamed using idc script.

I have provided a script below which can solve this problem. Although it can be modified to extract the subroutine offset `B00BA` from `sub_B00BA` and rename (or rather append) to a name of your liking, but I left that approach so that this script can more flexible (i.e you can change to any name and not just `SomeSubName_Offset`).

idc script: `rename_method.idc`

```
#include <idc.idc>

static main(void)
{
    auto ea, fncname, fstatus=-1;
    auto findsub="sub_B00BA";           // [1] Subroutine to find
    auto newsubName="CMyClass__B00BA" ; // [2] New name for the subroutine 
    for (ea=MinEA(); ea != BADADDR; ea=NextFunction(ea))
    {
        fncname = GetFunctionName(ea);                
        if (fncname == findsub) 
        {
            auto errcode = MakeNameEx(ea, newsubName, SN_PUBLIC|SN_CHECK|SN_NOWARN);
            if (errcode)
            {
                Refresh();
                RefreshLists();
                Message("[*] disassembly/subroutine-list refreshed..ok\n");
            }
            fstatus=1;
            return;
        }
    }
        if (fstatus == -1)  // if we don't have such function in disassembly
        {
            Message("[*] subroutine:" + findsub +
            " not found.\nplease check name of the subroutine/method again.\n");
        }
}
```

*Please make sure you change subroutine name at [1] and [2]. I have tested this script using IDA 6.6 and it will definitely work with IDA 7.x.*

Comment: This is one piece of the puzzle. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: You don't need to loop over every function comparing its name against the one you want. You can use `get_name_ea` instead. (In earlier versions of IDA like 6.6, it was known as `LocByName`.)